# Showing that $(1-\varepsilon)^2 \frac{E(X)^2}{E(X^2)} \leq P(X> \varepsilon E(X))$ for a positive random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm having problems with the following inequality. $X$ is a positive r.v. and $0 \leq \varepsilon < 1$.

$$(1-\varepsilon)^2 \frac{E(X)^2}{E(X^2)} \leq P(X> \varepsilon E(X)).$$

I could use a hint.

Comment: Please don't edit to destroy the content of your question, it prevents other users from viewing the question and disrespects the people who have taken effort to answer it.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$X= X.1_{\{X\leq \varepsilon E[X]\}}+ X.1_{\{X> \varepsilon E[X]\}} \\
\leq \varepsilon E[X] + X.1_{\{X> \varepsilon E[X]\}} \\
(1-\varepsilon)E[X] \leq E[X.1_{\{X> \varepsilon E[X]\}}]$$

Now apply Cauchy Schwarz on RHS and then square both sides to get your result.